# Best way to handle user registration

Tags: django

I'm following a tutorial in which we are using https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.io for registrations redux settings.

Since the tutorial is from 2015 I wanted to check if Djnago had more robust built in features for this, or if going with a 3rd party app such as the one linked to above was still a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth), it is stable and active. It offers local registration and as well as social authentication for many providers. For more registrations packages you can check this [grid](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/registration/).